# bibtex entry which attributes are use?

Tags: bibtex, biber

Is there any document when I can see which attributes are linked to a specific bibtex entry type? And which of them are printed? I know it is dependent on the style, but is there any document compiling the most used styles and entries?

Comment: If you are asking about `biblatex`, the standard data model, which is used by most styles (in some shape or form with minor modification) is documented in the manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), but this only describes sensible data for each entry type. It is still up to the style to decide if and how to print the data (the standard `biblatex` styles all behave in basically the same way here, so that should cover many cases, but contributed styles may be different). If you are asking about BibTeX `.bst` styles ...

Comment: ... then you can have a look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf for a skeleton of fields that most styles support, but there is more variability there (because they are fewer predefined fields).